# Building the data portion of $.ajax dynamically

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a need to build the data string dynamically. This is not working, as it is just passing the param variable as a string.

```
var parameters = "{foo: 'test'}";
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        data: parameters,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json
    });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You're *giving* it a string; give it an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first you assign a string to parameters variable, but then expect it to turn into object? ) Use object in the first place, like this:

```
var params = {foo: 'test'};
$.ajax({..., data: params, ...});
```

Comment: @tobyodavies: no one said it should be a JSON. I'm sure OP just don't know enough what they want :-)

Comment: Thanks, what if I want to send the value of a form element as a value?

Comment: @tobyodavies Hence `mimeType`, `contentType`, `processData`, `beforeSend`, using a string and setting `contentType`, and so on.

Comment: @JasonWells Either build it yourself, use [`.serializeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/), or other options.

Comment: @JasonWells Then collect it with $('some_input_selector').val() beforehand. Or even better, use [$.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) or [$.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/);

Comment: @raina77ow Yea I figured as much, but this did not work {foo: ('#bar').val()}

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm not sure I follow? My comment was that this is semantically different than OP's code, can you even set those properties when the request is GET?

Comment: Thanks raina77ow: one more question, how do I append a param to this list. I need to do if(){ append }

Comment: `if (something) { params[appendedParam] = appendedValue; }` should do the trick, I suppose. )

Answer (score 0):

```
var parameters = {foo:'test'};
//modify `parameters` dynamicaly
parameters[bar]='dynamic!';
$.ajax({
    //...
    data: (sendJSON?JSON.stringify(parameters):parameters) // sends params either JSON or form encoded
    //...
});
```

Comment: You don't need `JSON.stringify` here

Comment: @zerkms he is receiving JSON, I'm giving him the benefit of the doubt here, now I've shown both ways

Comment: @stevether given OP is using GET, you may be right that form encoding is what's actually desired

Comment: @tobyodavies: I'm sure OP just doesn't know there are alternatives, so he encodes it on the client and decodes back on the server